# Is there a way chart a date range without the last value? PBI

Tags: charts, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

On a line chart i have X dates by day and Y values. Question is how to **NOT display** the **current** day on that chart?

Comment: You can go to filters and then select the dates or values that you don't want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the filters under Filter on this visual panel.
There expanding the dates value use

> filter type: **relative date**, Show items when the value: is in the last: **days**, weeks, year etc..(as per your need) and finally **uncheck** the box **Include today** and *apply the filter*.

You may checkout the below screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: I see. Yeah, for days it worked, thanks. Would you know if that is also possible for weeks? In the same manner, that it shows the full history, but doesn't add the days of the current week until it has concluded.

Comment: you can add week in relative date but that can only exclude the last day or the current day when the query is running. You can try explicitly setting Advanced filtering and setting the dates range in filter value along with is on or after and is on or before parameter.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzkHY.png

Comment: Data has to be often updated, so no way ii can filter it the way i need. Done it through DAX by creating a new column with this code: 'W/O Current Week = 
var week = 'Calendar'[Date (week bins)]
var currentweek = LASTDATE(ALL('Calendar'[Date (week bins)]))
return
IF (week = currentweek, 1 , 0)'

Comment: oh I see, you meant it doesn't add the week until all its week days have occurred. I assumed the other way. Anyways DAX is cool! cheers